# Proxy for URL request on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a URL request to my server but the request needs to go through a proxy (IP address, not used for authentication). Can anyone get me any pointers on how to achieve this?

Can I programatically set a proxy for an URL request?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can set/enable HTTP proxy on you mac(development) machine and try the app on the simulator. I did this for one of my apps.

I am not sure how to do it programatically.